# Aborted operating system install keeps running on boot

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, installation, boot

I recently asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/231295/windows-7-install-crashes) about how I couldn't get Windows 7 installed on my system.

Since then it turns out my system is not compatible, however whenever I boot my machine the installer tries to run. There is a small window of time where I can use the arrow keys to navigate from `system install` to `earlier version of windows`

Can someone tell me how to cancel the install that is trying to run so that my system boots normally into my original windows install?

Edit 1, I have even removed the hard drive the new install was using, but to no avail.
Edit 2, The earlier version of windows is XP

Comment: So I can assume you're old Windows can still be booted? (And which version would that be?)

Comment: @Tobias, yes I can still boot into the `earlier version of windows` which is XP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Be warned**: These may make matters worse, especially if there is still a multi-boot in place.

### Using a Windows XP CD

If you have an Windows XP boot CD, you can [run the recovery console](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/recovery_console_overview.mspx?mfr=true) and use [`fixboot`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixboot.mspx?mfr=true) and/or [`fixmbr`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixmbr.mspx?mfr=true) to solve your problem.

[This page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314058) has more information about the Windows XP recovery console.

Finally, [this eHow article](http://www.ehow.com/how_4891476_reinstall-xp-bootloader.html) describes the whole process.

### Using a Windows 7 DVD

If you have a Windows 7 DVD, you may be able to restore the XP boot loader directly from Windows with the following command (run as an administrator):

```
[DVD Drive Letter]:\boot\bootsect.exe /nt52 ALL /force
```

Note that I have only tried the procedure with the Windows XP CD-ROM myself, so I cannot guarantee that this last approach works.

Comment: This hasn't work and has infact stopped me being able to access the earlier version of windows that was previously working. `Windows could not start because the following file is missing or corrupt: <WIndos root>\system32\hal.dll

Comment: Ouch. Perhaps the boot loader incorrectly tries to boot from the (former) Windows 7 partition/disk? In that case, would it be possible to remove that partition/disk and try this procedure again?

Comment: Now resolved by running `chkdsk -r` from the recovery console.

Comment: Very glad to hear it. @Alan

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Discussion in the comment thread showed that this is incorrect because the Bootloader that should be modified here has in fact been put there by Windows 7 setup. So MBRFix/FixMBR it is.

What's happening here is that Windows 7 setup is still registered in the Windows boot manager on your startup partition (that's the one Windows XP is on).

You'll need to delete Windows 7 setup from the Bootmanager list on your hard drive. There's an excellent article on Microsoft Support about this: [How to edit the Boot.ini file in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289022/en-us) You should be seeing two entries there: one for your Windows XP, and one for the Windows 7 installer. Remove the latter, and you should be fine from then on.

Comment: Windows 7 does not use `boot.ini` but [BCDedit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(WS.10).aspx).

Comment: Yes, but he needs to do that in Windows XP. (See the comment thread for the question)

Comment: Editing `boot.ini` will not have any effect on the Vista/7 boot loader, which is what displays "Earlier version of Windows" in the first place.

Comment: Dammit, you're right. The "earlier version of Windows" thing should have tipped me off that this is the W7 bootloader.

Comment: I could have easily missed that myself. :-)

Comment: +1 for the edit, I will look into this tonight, thanks